# Symfony3 Form Error - A form with an empty name cannot have a parent form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

My code was working fine, util this morning, I got error

```
[2018-08-17 12:39:42] request.INFO: Matched route "white_label_homepage". {"route":"white_label_homepage","route_parameters":{"_controller":"Bundle\\WhiteLabelBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"white_label_homepage"},"request_uri":"http://symfony/white-label","method":"GET"} []
[2018-08-17 12:39:42] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException: "A form with an empty name cannot have a parent form." at /home/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 270 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Form\\Exception\\LogicException(code: 0): A form with an empty name cannot have a parent form. at /home/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php:270)"} []
```

I don't wanna past the all code, but there is no explanation for this error nowhere to be found on internet :). So if someone can please elaborate what is this error mean. In docs there is no setting a name for a form, and there is no parent, so what is this error all about?

Comment: look all the forms used in the `white_label_homepage` route and check if they all have a `getName()` function which is a returning an **unique** form name

Comment: Thank you for that, but yes, I set the get name method in form class:


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'white_label_form';
    }

Comment: Does the form have any child forms? Do they all have names?

Comment: Does the form have any parent, all having an unique name ? (extending one of your custom form)

Comment: No I started from docs, created my first form, and everything worked till yesterday.

Comment: Can you please show the code of your custom form type?

Comment: It started to work... I did not do anything, I guess It will show up again sometimes during the demo, or on production :)

Answer (score 7):

Happens if you accidently pass an empty string to the form builder's `add()` method like in the following example:

```
$builder->add('');
```